# Woocommerce: on archive page after on_click add to cart show custom data via ajax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

So basically, what i want, to show product added in cart also on archive page. I did this functionality, you can refer with image (1 item- already in cart) but my code work on refresh the page. I want to show the same with ajax. As soon as "add to cart" clicked, the data added in mini cart, at same time data will show on product listing page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYDD0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
**Woocommerce > Settings > Products >  Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives**

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
 global $woocommerce;

    $return_to  = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
    $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
 return $message;
}
```

Comment: you didn't get my question, please check image for reference

Comment: So you have basically enable the ajax add to cart. You wish to show that message on the success of ajax. Am I getting you right now.

Comment: I need to show no. of specific product added in a cart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your product with quantity using Ajax then definitely WooCommerce default checkbox `Enable AJAX to add to cart buttons on archives` not works for quantity purpose.

There are many solutions to add this feature. I have implemented it earlier. You just need to add some classes, functions, and script to achieve this.

This is the [link](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/woocommerce-add-to-cart-with-quantity-and-ajax/) which is really helpful for me and you can go through it or you can also check [this](https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/5114131) one. It's not complicated.

If you want to add this in your headers like a mini cart or something. So for that, this one is the best [solution](https://sridharkatakam.com/adding-cart-icon-number-items-total-cost-nav-menu-using-woocommerce/) for you.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.